# Rails Paperclip: update vs. update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I realized something quite strange when attempting to upload an image via the paperclip gem for my user model (under the avatar attribute). For some reason there User.update and @user.update_attributes behaves differently. Does anyone know why this is so?

```
#using @user.update_attributes(user_avatar_params)
def update_profile_pic
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(user_avatar_params)
    puts @user.avatar_file_name.nil? # prints false as expected
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
end

#using User.update(@user.id, user_avatar_params)
def update_profile_pic
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    User.update(@user.id, user_avatar_params)
    puts @user.avatar_file_name.nil? # prints true although successfully saves
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
end
```

And here is my strong params in the user_controller.rb

```
def user_avatar_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
end
```

Comment: As affinities mentioned User.update returns the object based on the record it updated. So it is basically not the same object in the memory that user var point to.
Try: user = User.update(user.id, user_avatar_params) and I believe you will get the same results in both cases.

BTW, I think expected value in 'user.avatar_file_name.nil?' should be false, not true

Comment: Thanks for the catch @RoaringStones. I have corrected the post. Yes when I use ```@user = User.update(user.id, user_avatar_params)``` it prints false as I expected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`ActiveRecord.update` has a behavior that may be throwing you off:

> Updates an object (or multiple objects) and saves it to the database, if validations pass. The resulting object is returned whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not.
>   http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class

However the `update_attributes` will just return `false`.

Both of these use Model-level validations and so both should save or not save equally. However, the return values will be different.

As @RoaringStones pointed out, the solution is to use

```rb
user = User.update(user.id, user_avatar_params)
```

Comment: Yes I tried testing these in the exact same scenario.

Answer (score 55):

For what it's worth, as of Rails 4.0.2, [`#update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) returns `false` if the update failed, not simply the object which the update failed for. Of further note, [`#update_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes) is simply an alias of [`#update`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update) now.

Comment: _"For what it's worth"_ This is worth a lot. I'm glad I scrolled down passed the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 19):

By the way, `#update_attributes` gonna be deprecated from Rails 6 (though this is not released yet)

please have a look at

- https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31998
- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/5645149d3a27054450bd1130ff5715504638a5f5

for more details.